# Vuetify.js: v-dialog is not working when i close and open again

Tags: vuetify.js

I using a Vuetify.js for my project
when I used v-dialog component I got a problem that closing the v-dialog and open again.

here is my code.

`<div @click="dialog=true">click here</div>`

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog">
    <alert-popup />
</v-dialog>


data() {
return {
  dialog : false
 }
```

this is work when I open dialog first time but when I open again only can see the opacity black page
I don`t know which part is wrong.  please reply this question. thanks

Comment: it would be really nice if you can create a codepen

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide any code to reproduce the behavior. But I guess the you need provide `<v-card>` component inside the dialog component. If you don't provide that it just shows the opacity issue.Putting a `v-card` will eliminate the opacity issue.

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-row justify="start">
        <v-btn @click="openDialog">Open</v-btn>

        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="300px">

          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>My Dialog</v-card-title>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-text>
              This is text for dialog
            </v-card-text>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn x-small color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
              <v-btn x-small color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here is the [working code](https://codepen.io/sarojsasmal/pen/PoZvvZp) where there is a `v-card` component inside `v-dialog`.

I also see that you've used a custom component called `alert-popup` inside the `v-dialog`.If that is the case it needs to be refactored a bit to achieve what you're looking for.

- Creating a separate component which you are already doing except `<v-dialog>`.
- Emitting a close event from `<alert-popup>` component so that open/close and clicking open won't cause issue.

### HTML:

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-row justify="start">
        <v-btn @click="openDialog">Open</v-btn>
        <alert-popup :dialog="dialog" @close="closeMyDialog" />
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

### Javascript:

```
 let AlertPopup = Vue.component("AlertPopup", {
  props: {
    dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    open: false
  }),

  methods: {
    close() {
      this.open = false;
      this.$emit("close");
    }
  },
  watch: {
    dialog(value) {
      this.open = value;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.open = this.dialog;
  },
  template: `
    <v-dialog v-model="open" max-width="300px">

          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>My Dialog</v-card-title>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-text>
              This is text for dialog
            </v-card-text>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn x-small color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Close</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
`
});
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: {
    AlertPopup
  },
  data: (vm) => ({
    dialog: false
  }),

  computed: {},
  methods: {
    closeMyDialog() {
      this.dialog = false;
    },
    openDialog() {
      this.dialog = true;
    }
  }
});
```

If look at the `AlertPopup` component, it just take a prop named dialog and that we can pass from the main component, when button is clicked, it sets to true, which triggers the `AlertPopup` component.

NOTE:
If we don't emit the **close** event from the `AlertPopup` component, then the modal dialog will not open on the second time onwards. The reason for this behavior is the fact that, when the button is clicked from the parent component,which set the dialog to true and pass it to the `AlertPopup` and whatever things happens inside the `AlertPopup` remains inside that component and `dialog` property of parent component never changes.

Here is a [working example](https://codepen.io/sarojsasmal/pen/PoZvvZp?editors=1010) of how the modal component are triggered from parent component. If we remove the `close` event, it will not open the modal second time.

> Update:  It turns out we are unnecessary complicating things, we don't
> even need to emit an event, we can pass in the close function as a
> prop and react to that, whenever the close button is clicked, it would
> call the closeAlert().

Thanks to @Pratik149 for pointing out the bug, I have attached the click outside event handler.

Here is the completely re-factored code.

```
    <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-row justify="start">
        <v-btn @click="openDialog">Open</v-btn>
        <alert-popup :dialog="dialog" @close="closeMyDialog" :close="closeMyDialog" />
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

And the component logic is updated as follow

```
let AlertPopup = Vue.component("AlertPopup", {
  props: {
    dialog: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    close: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    open: false
  }),

  methods: {
    closeAlert() {
      this.close();
    }
  },

  template: `
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="300px" @click:outside="closeAlert">

          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>My Dialog</v-card-title>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-text>
              This is text for dialog
            </v-card-text>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn x-small color="blue darken-1" text @click="closeAlert">Close</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
`
});
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: {
    AlertPopup
  },
  data: (vm) => ({
    dialog: false
  }),

  computed: {},
  methods: {
    closeMyDialog() {
      debugger;
      this.dialog = false;
    },
    openDialog() {
      this.dialog = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Finally here is the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/saroj990/pen/BadLWwX?editors=1010)

Comment: I tried your codepen, it is still not working second time when I close the dialogue by clicking somewhere outside the dialogue

Comment: adding `@click:outside="closeMyDialog"` on v-dialogue opening tag did the trick for me. It calls the function when clicked outside of dialogue.

`<v-dialog v-model="open" max-width="300px" @click:outside="closeMyDialog">`